Macro for ungrouping shapes (particularly textboxes) within Excel workbook
I have a Macro for translating text within textbox shapes in an excel workbook, but it fails if any textboxes are grouped in any of the sheets. Is there an easy way to ungroup all shapes within a workbook through a VBA Macro?
Here is an example I found that works in Microsft Word, but it doesn't work in Excel:
Sub Ungroup()
Dim xNmbr As Integer
With ActiveDocument
    For xNmbr = .Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    .Shapes(xNmbr).Select
        Set thisshape = .Shapes(xNmbr)
        With thisshape.WrapFormat
       .Type = wdWrapSquare
    If thisshape.Type = msoGroup Then thisshape.Ungroup
    End With
    Next
End With
End Sub


Ungrouping shapes in Excel is very similar to Word. Of course you loop over shapes on a sheet, not a document.
Sub ungroupShapes(ws As Worksheet)
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In ws.Shapes
        If sh.Type = msoGroup Then
            sh.Ungroup
        End If
    Next
End Sub

But maybe you want to keep the group structure. For a group, you can loop over the shapes within that group using GroupItems. Maybe use a recursive routine like the following
Sub handleShapes(shapes As Variant)
    Dim sh As Shape
    DoEvents
    For Each sh In shapes
        If sh.Type = msoGroup Then
            handleShapes sh.GroupItems
        Else
            DoSomethingWithTheShape sh
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub DoSomethingWithTheShape(sh As Shape)
    Debug.Print sh.Name, sh.Type
End Sub

Just call the routine with something like
handleShapes ThisWorkbook.sheets(1).Shapes
' or
handleShapes ActiveSheet.Shapes
' or
For Each ws in Thisworkbook.Worksheets
    handleShapes ws
Next ws

Unfortunately, the type of Shapes of a worksheet is different from the child shapes of a group, so the parameter of handleShapes needs to be of type Variant.
The DoSomethingWithTheShape is just a placeholder for the action you want to do on a sheet (translating text).
